# Как настроить сборку кросскомпилятора при использовании старой версии

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть библиотеки собранные в старой версии кьют (4.6.0), и есть свежий creator, так же есть проект написанный и работающий  для малины в версии кьют 5.6.
Что нужно для того что бы собрать этот проект для тех устаревших библиотек?

Comment: У вас два варианта - поставить Qt той же версии, что и собранные библиотеки и попытаться собрать им ваш проект, попутно молясь чтобы в проекте не было ничего несовместимого со старой версией Qt, в противном случае исправлять (при возможности). Или же пересобрать библиотеки свежей версией кьюта.

Comment: в 4.6 не было крейтора фри, а погромист из меня так се.. Ну а собрать все для новой версии нет рабочей портянки серия mcu imx28 от NXP ссылка на инструкцию давно протухла                           ну и основная проблема что даже для этих библиотек нужно собрать свой qmake,  чего я не могу сделать без инструкции

Comment: "даже для этих библиотек нужно собрать свой qmake" зачем? вроде достаточно установки Qt нужной версии.

Comment: ну для малины же зачемто собирается свой собственный qmake..

Comment: если пребилда Qt на малину нет (не помню), то будет собираться весь Qt, с библиотеками и всеми тулзами, включая qmake, если я правильно вас понимаю. В вашем случае, что-то пересобирать все же придется

Comment: я согласен собрать, нет проблем, есть инструкция для малины, собственно вся соль в такой команде `./configure -release -opengl es2 -device <rpi-version> -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v` какой аргумент device для imx28?